# Звуки Э и Е в русском языке

Tags: фонетика, лексика, транскрипция

От чего зависит произношение звука Е и Э в заимствованных словах? Почему мы говорим, например, "пионЕр", "берЕт", "тЕория", но "тЭрмос", "орхидЭя" (хотя я говорю упрямо "орхидЕя"), "контЭйнер" и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главным образом - от степени ассимиляции слова русским языком. Чем более "обкатано" слово, тем вернее там появляется Е вместо Э (т.е. мягкость предшествующего согласного).

В отношении орхидеи ваше упрямство, похоже, оправдано. Словари пока не фиксируют вариант [де], но это, думаю, дело времени.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна относительно ассимиляции. Но орфоэпические нормы надо соблюдать.

Comment: А кто или что против соблюдения норм?